# Override GET or any default method on strongloop

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I need to override the GET on strongloop. So when I GET foo/ it returns something different as the default one.

I tried using `remoteMethod` with `http: {path: '/', verb: 'get'}` without success.

How can I override any default method on strongloop?

Answer (score 13):

Finally I found it.
So get corresponds to **find** without any filter.

So the code is:

```
Foo.on('attached', function() {
  Foo.find = function(filter, callback) {
    //Whatever you need to do here...
    callback(null, {hello: 'hello'});
  }
});
```

Here there is a link for all the [PersistedModel methods](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-find)

I just put **'attached'** without exactly knowing why so if someone can comment the reason it would be great.

Comment: the `attached` event indicates `Foo` model was attached to the loopback app instance, so you can overwrite at this moment the behaviour of the `find` remote method. Yo can see it on loopback code:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/6964914bab64496c789c434fec39d2914231ee23/lib/model.js#L73